# Why can't I select a page in my website when using SXA?

Tags: sxa

I have created a new SXA site (using Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.1 rev. 161004 for 8.2.zip) and I've created several different pages (inside of Content Editor). I'm trying to use the Navigation component to provide a sub-navigation menu. So I go to the **Control Properties**, and go to the **Navigation Settings** to select a Start Page. When I click on the down arrow to select my start page, none of the pages show up underneath my **Home** node. Here's what I'm seeing:
[image: Missing Web Pages]

- Is there some kind of security that I bypassed when creating those pages in content editor?
- How can I get any pages to show up underneath the Home node?

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot or tell us what you see while selecting **Start Page**? Is there **Home** item only?

Comment: I added the pages by simply right-clicking on the Home Page and clicked on the Insert -> Page item. This ended up using the  /sitecore/templates/Project/Enterprise/Page - {86358F86-EAFA-42D8-B05A-91806F5A53F0} template. The Enterprise part in the path is the name for the **Tenant** that I chose. That page is based on the /sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Multisite/Content/Page template.

Comment: Thanks for the Information, Solution worked ...!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answer 1

No there is no security. You did everything fine

**Explanation**:

When you open following item: `/sitecore/templates/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Navigation/Rendering Parameters/Navigation/Navigation Settings/NavigationRoot` you will notice that inside **Source** field there is following token `query:$home`.

This token should be resolved to start item of your site. Nothing else special here, standard Droptree field with dynamic source

#### Answer 2

My theory is that you created your site on **SXA 1.0**.

There was an issue in site scaffolding and not all fields were populated correctly.

**Solution:**

Navigate to your **site definition** item (`/sitecore/content/Group/Tenant/site/Settings/Site Grouping/site`) and make sure that **Start Item** field is set.

[image]

I suppose that in your case it is not, thus you can see not **your Home** item but **default Sitecore Home item** because `$home` token in Navigation Rendering Parameters  was incorrectly resolved.

You can also notice that by looking at the **Home** item icon as well. **SXA** home template icon is slightly different.

#### Closing Words

In **SXA 1.1** this issue has been resolved and you no longer need to define **Star Item** manually.

### Additional solution

This solution is for people who could not solve their issue with the solution provided above.

There is some rare case when, even if you have got everything configured properly your site is resolved incorrectly, thus some functionalities might not work as expected (navigation is a great example).

**How do I know if I am experiencing that extra case**

Assuming that you configured everything like I described above and you open a page using **Experience Editor** button from **Content Editor** and gets `sc_site` query parameter with **website** value or value different than your site definition item name then you've got a problem.

**How to mitigate this:**

To mitigate that issue you have to reconfigure standard Sitecore website a little bit. What we want is **rootPath** property cannot be a substring of any other **SXA** based sites **rootPath**.

Default value is`rootPath="/sitecore/content"` and we need to make it more unique, for example `rootPath="/sitecore/content/default"`.

Then you have to create any item under `/sitecore/content` and move  default Sitecore Home item there.

#### Summary

This is a workaround for a small issue that we've found with @keith-vanderveen in site info resolution logic.

This issue should be fixed in the next release of **SXA**.

**Affected versions:**

SXA 1.0, SXA 1.1

Comment: I'm using **Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.1 rev. 161004 for 8.2.zip**. I should have specified that in the OP. I am seeing the Start Item defined properly. The Home item icon information is very helpful.

Comment: So your problem still exist or after changing it everything works fine?

Comment: The problem still exists. The values that you said should be there were already there.

Comment: I've another theory. Could you invoke this piece of code in **SPE**?
`[Sitecore.Sites.SiteManager]::GetSites()` and let me know what is the order of sites. What we need to know is whether **website** site is the last site after your sites (should be before **schedule**, **system**, **publisher**

Comment: **website** is the last site before scheduler, system, and publisher. It is also listed after my website. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Let's try another one. Please open **SPE** ISE and run those two lines `Import-Function Get-SiteItem
Get-SiteItem (gi "/sitecore/content/Group/Tenant/site/Home")`
(please change the path to your path to the item where you tried configure navigation rendering.
This should return an item. Item should be a site definition item (if everything works fine).

Comment: Here's what I got from running those commands: 
Name                             Children Language Version Id                                     TemplateName
----                             -------- -------- ------- --                                     ------------
Boundless                        True     en       1       {A2F2FDE2-2B22-49B0-BCF1-33483324AC2B} Site

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48208/discussion-between-alan-plocieniak-and-keith-vanderveen).